# MvvmCross navigation from Xamarin Forms TabbedPage to a Native view while preserving history/backstack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, presenter

[image: Something like this]

I am hoping to do something like the image above, using MvvmCross, Xamarin Forms and Native Views. The image is for demonstration purpose, the actual UIs are more complicated. I have looked into the MvvmCross Playground project, as well as the source codes for the presenters (i.e. MvxForms[Ios||Android]ViewPresenter and MvxFormsPagePresenter). I created a custom presenter from the MvxForms[Ios||Android]ViewPresenter and tried to show the native view (view controller/fragment) as a navigation page, but I was not successful. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Apologize in advance if this question is a duplicate. I did a fair amount of searching, but could not find exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you want to move to a native page. You can just navigate to a forms page and use custom render to render native views. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not too familiar with the custom render. From what I can tell, custom render is use for converting Xamarin Forms -> Native views. Currently, using the MvxFormsPagePresenter can show the Xamarin Forms Pages & Native Views just fine (without any extra work), just that I could not figure out how to navigate from Forms Page to Native View while keeping the history or backstack, so that Native View can go back to the Forms Page (as the image shown above). I did not find any docs on rendering native view to a navigation page. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that we just started using Xamarin.Forms, all the UIs were created with platform native views. We have only updated the main page and it's content pages to be Forms TabbedPages.

Comment: I'm not into native to forms navigation.  Sorry

Comment: @Error280MonkeyFound: That's ok! Thank you so much for your suggestion. :)